# Getting Plink serial connection to return to cmd or end

Tags: cmd, serial-port, putty, plink

I am using command line PuTTY (`plink`) in `cmd` for some automation. I was able to redirect some commands to execute some serial comport commands to my device.  However, once it finishes executing the commands, the serial connection stays active and `plink` never returns to `cmd` or closes.  Is there a way to make this happen?  The only way I can get it to exit is to hit `ctrl+c` on the keyboard, which breaks my automation.

For example:

```
plink -serial -sercfg 115200 COM7 < somecommands.txt
```

This executes then just stays in the plink serial session.

My only way around it is to use `taskkill` to exit.

Thanks a bunch!